# php include, alternative via javascript - web and cordova tested

Tags: javascript, cordova, include

save for me and for posterity

this is a alternative include created via javascript.
I tested and working on cordova (web and android).

```
    function jsinclude()
    {
        let x, i, el, file, request;

        /*loop all doc el*/
        x = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {

            el = x[i];                          //el by el
            file = el.getAttribute("include");  //get path

            if (file)
            {
                //check the path error
                if (file.startsWith("/") )
                { 
                    alert("\n\nerror in file path: do not use the ' / ' as initial.\n\n\Follow the example below:\n<div include='myfolder/.../file.html'></div>\n\n");
                    let mex = '<p style="backraound:white !important; padding:20px !important; border: 1px solid red !important; color:red !important; font-weight:bold !important;"> !! ERROR: WRONG PATH FOR INCLUDE</p>';
                    el.innerHTML = mex;
                };

                //create HTTP request
                request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.onload = function ()
                //request.onreadystatechange = function ()  //simple alternative
                {

                    if (this.status == 200 ) // if ok
                    {
                        console.log("include-js: inlcude file: " + file +" | rquest status: "+this.status+" | data printed: "+this.responseText);
                        el.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                    else if (this.status == 404) // if ok... but not found
                    {
                        alert("error in file path or server:\n404 file not founded.");
                    }
                    else if (this.status != (404 && 0 && 200)) // if... wtf!??
                    {
                        alert("undefined server error on include js");
                    }

                    // stop and repeat
                    el.removeAttribute("include");
                    jsinclude();

                }

                // sand all... and exit
                request.open("GET", file, true);
                request.send();
                return;
            }
        }

};
```

every tag inside the body it works perfectly.

```
<body>
    <div include="yourpath/test.html">
        included html content ;)
    </div>
</body>
```

*Read note for include the head content*

```
<head include="yourpath/head meta etc.html">

    content loaded... (read note)

</head>
```

---

**NOTE: *I have not tested if, after including the head, it continue to block the other script inside the head tag (for now).***

Comment: obviously if you want to help me improve it ... write it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php include alternative with javascript - problem on head tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864177/php-include-alternative-with-javascript-problem-on-head-tag)

Comment: You just resubmitted your previous post. I don't see how this is related to cordova. There are a lot better ways to include (template) files, this is really weird approach.

Comment: @somerandomusername no I understand why it's weird but ok. What's your approach to include a section of code from an external file within a theme in a cross-app? Do you have better solutions?

Comment: Have you considered any JS frameworks like React or Angular, they work great with cross-platform systems. If you don't want to learn any of these frameworks, but I strongly advice you do, you can try out any of number of JS templating frameworks out there. That way you can still do vanilla js but have some extra help with managing content. Now you basically are trying to solve a problem that has been solved 100s of times

Comment: sorry but what does it mean? If I can do it because I have to study a library that, sooner or later, will be replaced?

Comment: I do not think it is useful to use a library without knowing how to disassemble it almost completely. It's like talking without knowing how to write.

do the work by if it means learning something that will remain for the quadruple of time!

Comment: Well by that logic you shouldn't use cordova, but learn how to package web content into native app on your own. If your goal is just to learn and try to create everything on your own then sure, but even better lesson would be to learn how to use all the tools available to you.

Comment: @somerandomusername
 
ok ... it 'isnt wrong. But we dont exaggerate! Js is the base. Creating the whole system to build a cordova style web-app becomes extreme! Although the reasoning is valid, as you put it then you "fuck everything and we use wix!" 
while I want to avoid being one of those who uses bootstrap but does not know the css, or jquery and does not know javascript! come on then

+ learn - lean on the already done!

<: D hahahaha